# Se puede resolver en un tiempo aceptable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, criptografía

Dada la función:

```
def md5(r, n):
    i = 0
    while i != n:
        r = hashlib.md5(r[:9]).hexdigest()
        i+=1
    return r
```

Results:

```
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 0) #00000000000000000000000000000000
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 1) #4c93008615c2d041e33ebac605d14b5b
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2) #c6246d2a39695fb74971b09ced30874f
md5("4c93008615c2d041e33ebac605d14b5b", 1) #c6246d2a39695fb74971b09ced30874f
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2017) #57ab27ac3626d4565913485ff42b037b
```

Hay forma de calcular:

```
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2017201720172017)
```

Sin morir antes, claro.

`md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 20172017)` me toma 84 segundos, por lo tanto 2017201720172017 es 100000001 veces eso. Aproximadamente 2 millones de horas.

No uso `xrange` o `range` ya que el valor 2017201720172017 es muy grande.

Comment: Hola Jorge! "tiempo aceptable" y "sin morir antes" no son muy objetivos. Puedes decir el tiempo que te está tardando y el tiempo que consideras limite? Ademas no solo tiene que ver el codigo si no el Pc que uses. (aunque sin duda el codigo es clave)

Comment: Por tiempo debe estar tardando un poco... son 2 trillones de iteraciones... Yo más bien preguntaría sobre la utilidad práctica de realizar una iteración tan salvaje

Comment: Creo que ya sabes la respuesta a tu pregunta...

Comment: `md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 20172017)` me toma 84 segundos, por lo tanto 2017201720172017 es 100000001 veces eso. Aproximadamente 2 millones de horas.

Comment: Utilidad practica no tiene, la pregunta es de un ejercicio. Pero pienso que esta mar formulada.

Comment: Hasta donde sé, no hay forma de simplificar el algoritmo md5... tienes que pasar por todas las iteraciones, luego salvo que se me esté pasando algo no veo que esta pregunta tenga mucho futuro

Comment: Imagino que la única forma es usar una super computadora

Comment: Estaba dudando de responder. Por un lado, sí que queda margen para la optimización, como evitar crear un nuevo objeto en cada iteración del bucle o usar `xrange` (no hay absolutamente nada que te impida usar `xrange` si tienes 2 millones de horas disponibles para gastar en ello). Pero la pregunta que haces es que quieres hacerlo *"antes de morir en el intento"* y me temo mucho que no hay forma alguna de conseguirlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estimados, luego de romperme la cabeza algunos días pude llegar al resultado sin usar una supercomputadora cuántica. Cabe aclar que solo es para el calculo de

`md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2017201720172017)`

Como se toman los primeros nueve caracteres para la proxima iteración, es de suponer que en algun momento se iban a repetir.
Guardando y comparando los resultados anteriores se pudo determinar que luego de la iteracion 333399 se producia una repeticion de resultados conocidos de 60301 iteraciones, es decir:

```
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 333399) #70cd169443daf8cd4ed80be9b5cd5cf5
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 393700) #70cd169443daf8cd4ed80be9b5cd5cf5
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 454001) #70cd169443daf8cd4ed80be9b5cd5cf5
...
```

Dan todas el mismo resultado.

Por tanto se procedió a calcular:

**(2017201720172017 - 333399) Mod 60301 = 45742**

*El resultado de 45742 seria el desplazamiento de la iteracion 2017201720172017 en el intervalo de 60301 que se repite.*

Entonces:

```
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 379141) #9b723333387a123b2ff1840d7ac2472d
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 439442) #9b723333387a123b2ff1840d7ac2472d
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 499743) #9b723333387a123b2ff1840d7ac2472d
...
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2017201720172017) #9b723333387a123b2ff1840d7ac2472d
```

Por lo tanto no fue necesario calcular las 2017201720172017 iteraciones, sino solamente 379141.

En formula generica seria algo asi (no soy matematico):

`r(i)=r((i - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399)`

Ej:

`r(401265) = r((401265 - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399) = r(340964)
r(74589651) = r((74589651 - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399) = r(359120)
r(201720172017) = r((201720172017 - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399) = r(362302)
r(20122017) = r((20122017 - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399) = r(343289)
r(2017201720172017) = r((2017201720172017 - 333399) Mod 60301 + 333399) = r(379141)`

Donde i es la iteracion buscada y i >= 333399

r es el resultado de llamar la función md5 con parametros "00000000000000000000000000000000" e i

Ej:

`r(401265) = md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 401265)
r(340964) = md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 340964)
r(2017201720172017) = md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 201720172017) #Imposible de resolver
r(379141) = md5("00000000000000000000000000000000", 379141) #Mismo resultado que el anterior`

Un saludo grande a todos.

Comment: Me resultan raros tus ejemplos, 379141, 439442, 499743. ¿ No debería de ser la repetición cada `333399-60301=273098` ? 333399, 606497, ...

Comment: Además de lo que comenta Trauma, sería genial si pudieses aclarar el por qué de esta repetición, y si este caso aplica sólo para `"0000..."`, o para cualquier texto. Asumiendo que es sólo para este texto, entiendo que la respuesta general debería mostrar el algoritmo para calcular el hash de cualquier texto.

Comment: La repetición se da cada 60301 veces, a partir de la 333399. De ahi que el resultado que se obtiene en 333399 es el mismo que en _333399+1*60301=393700_ y en _333399+2*60301=454001_ (agrego en formula la formula generica).  Es solo para este caso, ya que yo quería encontrar el resultado para el caso particular de `"00000...."`. Para otro texto se debe determinar en que iteración comienzan las repeticiones y cada cuanto es el ciclo.

Comment: Lo único que saco en claro de aquí es que es un *fallo* conocido de MD5. Llega un momento en el que los primeros 72 bits del hash son iguales a los primeros 72 bits de los datos. No se me ocurre ninguna explicación matemática o estadística que lo explique, aparte del propio funcionamiento interno de MD5. Un caso aislado, valla. Y, si es un ejercicio, es porque ya es conocido.

Answer (score 4):

## Sí, pero con una supercomputadora cuántica.

---

Coincido con este comentario:

> [Imagino que la única forma es usar una super computadora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47414/se-puede-resolver-en-un-tiempo-aceptable#comment82832_47414) – [w33haa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1301/w33haa)

El [***tiempo de Planck***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_Planck) dice que en un segundo existen 10<sup>43</sup> instantes de tiempo.

```
md5("00000000000000000000000000000000" ...
```

La longitud de eso es 32, entonces la cantidad de hashes *MD5* que pueden existir es:

> 16 elevado a la 32. Eso es aproximádamente 3*10<sup>38</sup>

Suponiendo que a cada hash le cuesta mil instantes de tiempo:

> 3*10<sup>38</sup> * 10<sup>3</sup> es 3*10<sup>41</sup>, es decir, una **centésima de segundo**.

Esto significa que es físicamente posible calcular hash a un tiempo muy corto, pero por el momento ninguna computadora es tan rápida. Vamos a tomar como aceptable 100 años, hay gente que vive más que eso. Entonces hacemos la cuenta, 100 años dividido 16<sup>32</sup>.

Según el [calendario gregoriano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendario_gregoriano), en 100 años hay 3<sub>k</sub>155<sub>1</sub>695200 segundos. Eso dividido entre 16<sup>32</sup> da:

> Aproximadamente 1 / 107<sub>k</sub>831<sub>4</sub>189438<sub>3</sub>364789<sub>2</sub>940224<sub>1</sub>457493

El resultado es, uno sobre 100 mil cuatrillones de segundos, es decir, 9 * 10<sup>-30</sup> segundos.

Esa es la cantidad de tiempo que necesita la supercomputadora en comprobar cada hash, aceptando que puede terminar en 100 años. Actualmente una computadora normal ronda los 10 <sup>-8</sup> cada hash, con la ayuda de toda una humanidad quizás sería posible, o quizás en una época futura, no muy lejana.

Comment: Si te fijas bien en el algoritmo, cada iteración toma únicamente los primeros 9 dígitos para calcular el siguiente hash. Esto significa que existen `16**9` posibles entradas en lugar de `16**32` (`==2**128`). Si podemos calcular cada hash en 1 ns., podríamos solucionar el problema en unos 68 años.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Mi idea era mantener fijo el valor 100 años... Hice el cálculo, si quiero que tarde 100 años, para 9 dígitos hexadecimales, la computadora debe hacer 22 hash por segundo... Si quiero que tarde un año, 2178 por segundo.

Answer (score 2):

Como indico en mi comentario a la auto-respuesta, no me queda nada claro la solución. Después de pensarlo bastante, me animo a escribir esto.

Al grano: **Si**.

Si analizamos el código de ejemplo mostrado en la pregunta

```
r = hashlib.md5( r[:9]).hexdigest( )
```

observamos claramente que lo único que nos interesa son **los primeros 72 bits** (8 * 9). Además, salvo la primera vez, usamos como entrada los primeros 72 bits de la salida.

Analizando la pregunta, podemos reescribirla así:

> Dada una *secuencia* de datos de entrada compuesta por datos de `72 bits`, encontrar el valor máximo posible en dicha secuencia, antes de que comiencen a repetirse sus valores.

Lo cuál, a su vez, puede reescribirse como **2** preguntas separadas:

1. Dada una *secuencia* de datos de entrada, compuesta por datos de `72` bits, ¿ dicha secuencia contará con elementos repetidos **antes** de alcanzar el máximo valor posible para esos 72 bits ?
2. Si la respuesta es afirmativa, ¿ cuantos bits necesitamos para estar seguros de encontrar el primer elemento repetido ?

Asi que, como dijo *Jack el Destripador*, vamos por partes ...

#### ¿ Existirá la repetición antes de llegar al límite de 72 bits ?

Técnicamente, lo que buscamos es la existencia o no de *[una colisión de resumen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colisi%C3%B3n_(hash))*. Copiado directamente del enlace anterior

> En informática, una colisión de hash es una situación que se produce cuando dos entradas distintas a una función de hash producen la misma salida.

¿ Porqué buscamos una colisión ? pues muy sencillo. Si somos capaces, dentro del rango de 72 bits, de encontrar **2** valores que generen los mismos 72 bits como salida, entraremos **inevitablemete** en un bucle, del que no hay forma de salir.

Recordemos que los datos de salida son, a su vez, usados como datos de entrada. Unos *hipotéticos* datos de salida (que son entradas de la siguiente iteración):

> 1, 9, 4, 21, 3, 10, 17, 4, 21, ...

Se observa que tanto `9` como `17` **generan la misma salida** (4 en este ejemplo). En el `17` empieza el bucle.

Ahora, tras [consultar el funcionamiento de MD5](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), nos encontramos con el *primer escollo*. Aunque tan solo usemos 72 bits, la función trabaja, *internamente*, con 128 bits. Y ofrece resultados de ese mismo tamaño.

La *intuición* nos indica que **no habrá colisiones**, puesto que el ancho de las salidas en **mayor** que las entradas. Pronto caemos en el detalle de que **solo usamos 72 bits**. El resto de los datos (56 bits) **se repite siempre, en todas las entradas**. Con ello, estamos *limitando artificialmente* el ancho de las salidas. A efectos prácticos, las salidas contendrán **solo** 72 bits.

Aún así, no está claro que puedan existir repeticiones. Es necesario revisar *mas a fondo* el interior de MD5, hasta que caemos en la cuenta de una cosa:

> MD5 utiliza, internamente, operaciones que toman como entrada 96 bits, y generan una salida de **tan solo 32 bits**

Con eso es suficiente. **Es imposible** *mapear* 96 bits en **solo** 32 **sin que exitan salidas repetidas para distintos datos de entrada**. Aunque *mezclemos* distintas operaciones, la *perdida* de información se producirá, y con ella la seguridad de que tendremos salidas repetidas.

Por tanto, la respuesta a nuestra primera pregunta es:

> Si, existirá la repetición antes de llegar al límite de 72 bits.

Ahora, toca nuestra segunda pregunta.

#### ¿ Cuando se producirá esa repetición ?

El tema de las *colisiones de hash* ha sido ampliamente estudiado; el mejor método conocido es el [`Ataque del cumpleaños`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_cumplea%C3%B1os). Dicho ataque se basa en la *probabilidad*; nos indica un la probabilidad de que, tras cierto número de intentos, encontremos dos datos de entrada que generen el mismo resultado.

Desgraciadamente, mis conocimientos matemáticos *no dan para tanto*. Afortunadamente, en el enlace anterior tenemos una tabla. Usándola, deducimos que, para 72 bits de datos, el número de *intentos* necesarios, para una una probabilidad del 50%, estará entre `5.1 × 10^9` y `2.2 × 10^19`. Como vemos, un número *nada despreciable*.

Ahora, teniendo en cuenta que estamos hablando de *probabilidades*, la respuesta a nuestra segunda pregunta es algo mas *imprecisa*:

> No lo sabemos. Puede que en primer ciclo. Puede que en el último.

Por tanto, la respuesta a la pregunta original ¿ es posible hacerlo en un tiempo *razonable* ? es *curiosa*:

> Si

#### ¿ Y porqué si es posible ?

Por lo dicho antes sobre el `ataque del cumpleaños`. Estamos hablando de *probabilidades*, **no** de *datos seguros*.

Sería posible (aunque poco probable) que entráramos en bucle *en la segunda iteración* (en la primera no. Seguro). También **es posible** que entremos al bucle en la última.

Una vez *soltado el rollo*, me reafirmo en mi comentario. Aunque no se indique, tiene toda la pinta de ser un ejercicio. La casualidad de escoger esos datos concretos es bastante *improbable*. Por lo tanto, concluyo que es una *característica* conocida de MD5, seguramente descubierta durante las múltiples pruebas a las que ha sido dometida.