# Convertir código iterativo en aritmético

Tags: matemáticas, lenguaje-agnóstico

Mirando esta pregunta:

[¿ Se puede resolver en un tiempo aceptable ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47414/19610)

Me ha surgido una duda; a ver si se me entiende con un ejemplo.

> Resultado de la suma de números enteros consecutivos: sumar los números del 1 al 100.

Esta sencilla operación se puede realizar mediante, como mínimo, **2** formas diferentes:

1. Un bucle, con una variable *acumulador*, en la que van sumando los sucesivos valores.
2. Usar la fórmula matemática al efecto: `Sn = ( a1 + an ) / 2 * n`

Entiendo que la pregunta pudiera *estar basada en opiniones*, aunque no lo creo. Tampoco creo que sea equivalente a la *aun sin responder* `¿ P = NP ?`.

La pregunta, pues, es la siguiente:

¿ Toda operación *iterativa* puede expresarse en forma **no** iterativa ?

**EDITO**

Después de leer el comentario de @StefanNolde (gracias ;-) ), me he dado cuenta de un detalle, que concreta aún más la pregunta: en caso de respuesta afirmativa, solo sería posible si todas las operaciones en la *versión iterativa* son **reversibles**; como reversibles, tendríamos la suma `+`, resta `-`, multiplicación `*`, ... Y como **no reversibles**, la única que se me ocurre es el **desplazamiento de bits** (con lo que perdemos información).

Re-escribo la pregunta:

Suponiendo una operación *iterativa*, en la que todos sus pasos internos son reversibles, ¿ **siempre** es posible expresarla como una operación **no** iterativa ?

Comment: Pregunta muy interesante, lo he visto antes con un caso especiál al reves, si se puede siempre remplazar una operación recursiva por una iterativa. Mi primer instinto sería asumir que si, dado un sistema que es Turing completo, aun todavía no se me ocurre como comprobarlo.